Geonode project: deploy at subfolder
I trying to deploy geonode-project at subfolder.
By now, I succesfully done the following:

changed static and upload urls in settings
added prefix to all urls, like re_path(r"^my_prefix", include("geonode.urls"))

But, problem is, all links on pages still point to /original_url, not to /my_prefix/original_url, although I've rebuild everything with docker compose build --no-cache. Script paths, api endpoints, and static paths are all correct now.
What do I missing?

Figured out a little bit. Geonode uses geonode_mapstore_client, which has a bunch of harcoded urls:

https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-mapstore-client/blob/master/geonode_mapstore_client/templatetags/get_menu_json.py
https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-mapstore-client/blob/master/geonode_mapstore_client/templates/geonode-mapstore-client/snippets/footer.html

Also, you can set MAPSTORE_TRANSLATIONS_PATH and MAPSTORE_EXTENSIONS_FOLDER_PATH in settings.py (https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode-mapstore-client/blob/master/geonode_mapstore_client/context_processors.py)
These can be also changed here, or overriden
And finally, there's one more config (json) here

Still, didn't managed to make it work, just added subdomain
